# Angular interpolation inside of ternary expression

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ternary-operator

I have a bit of html inside of a div with values all expressed through interpolation. I'm also using a ternary operator to conditionally express part of my sentence.

```
{{activity.oxygenFullName}} {{convertStageTypeToText(activity.type)}} {{activity.addedUtc |
                        date:'short'}} {{activity.type == 'Deployment Scheduled' ? 'to be deployed at ' {{activity.deployment.completedUtc | date: 'short'}} : null}}
```

I'm getting a good amount of errors trying to include this interpolation inside of the ternary. I'm looking for the proper way to write this expression.

Comment: Put simply: you can't do that. In general, with anything this complex, I'd move the logic to an accessor and simplify the template.

Comment: I'm definitely aware of this simple truth. Hence my question. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Just use ngIf on a container

```
{{activity.oxygenFullName}} {{convertStageTypeToText(activity.type)}} {{activity.addedUtc |
                        date:'short'}}
<ng-container *ngIf="activity.type == 'Deployment Scheduled'">
  to be deployed at {{activity.deployment.completedUtc | date: 'short'}}
</ng-container>
```